# R shiny Highcharts tooltip: adding average as extra variable

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

I have a data.frame with multiple series that I'm plotting through the great Highcharts.

The issue that i'm facing: I can sum up all the values of the different series through the point.value variable in the Footerformat, but I can't seem to find out how you can display the average of all the series. Is this available? I don't find it in the documentation.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
library(highcharter)

df <- data.frame(timestamp = c("2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-05","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-05"),
                 series1 = c("series 1","series 1","series 1","series 1","series 1","series 2","series 2","series 2","series 2","series 2"),
                 series2 = c(6,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,2))

df$timestamp <- as.Date(df$timestamp, format = "%Y-%d-%m")
df$timestamp2 <- format(as.Date(df$timestamp), "%b-%y")


highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(title = "Time", categories = df$timestamp2)%>%
  hc_title(text = "in '000 metric tonnes",
           margin = 0, align = "left", 
           style = list(fontSize = 15, useHTML = TRUE, color = '#808080')) %>%
  hc_add_series(df, type = "line", hcaes(x = timestamp2, group = series1, y = series2))%>%
  # hc_plotOptions(area = list(stacking = "normal"))%>%
  hc_tooltip(headerFormat = '<large style="font-size:15px;"><b>{point.key}</b></large>
                              <br>
               <table style="width:200px">
               <col style="width:50%">
               <col style="width:50%">
               <tr>  <th style="text-align:left;"><b><u>Group </u></b></th> <th style="text-align: right;"><b><u> Volume </u></b></th> </tr>',
             pointFormat = '<tr><td style="text-align: left;color:{point.color}"><b>{series.name}: </b></td> <td style="text-align: right">{point.series2} k tons</td> </tr>',
             footerFormat = '<th style="text-align:left;"><b><u>Average: </u></b></th><td style="text-align: right"><b>{ } k tons </b></td> </table>', useHTML = TRUE, crosshairs = TRUE, table = TRUE)
```

Thanks in advance for advising me on this topic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no such options from the default, but I think it could be created using the tooltip.formatter function available from the Highcharts API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Here you can find an article showing how to work with Highcharts JavaScript syntax in R:
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/?fbclid=IwAR39-dztCuBUrncLQHEo9yNin00lRZfSqKY1JqAdvMU7KkokZGfTfj5DYB4